# Insert inferred type annotation for Scala val/var/def

Tags: scala, types, code-generation, type-inference

At the moment, I type in type annotations for public `val`s, `var`s and `def`s in my Scala classes, traits and objects[1] - either by inferring the types of them mentally, or occasionally by hovering over the identifier in Eclipse to find out what the presentation compiler thinks the type should be[2]. How can I conveniently add these type annotations automatically?

The purpose of adding in explicit types is to "lock in" the type of a public member of a template, so that if a developer changes the definition of the member in future in a way that results in an incompatible type, they will get a compile-time error unless they deliberately change the type annotation as well.

Footnotes:

[1] except if they override a member in a supertype and the type should be the same as the type of the overridden member, which is usually the case for overrides in my code.

[2] This isn't always correct; the presentation compiler seems to be weak when it comes to members that override members in supertypes.

Comment: I believe that IntelliJ IDEA does have a "insert inferred type" refactor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has [been implemented](https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1001433#/activity/ticket) in the Scala IDE in Kepler Eclipse 4.3 update.

Use ctrl/cmd-1 on the identifier and choose "Add explicit type ...".

See [here](http://scala-ide.org/docs/4.0.x/features/typingviewing/quick-fixes.html#Add_Explicit_Type_new).

Comment: Any equivalent in intelliJ?

Answer (score 2):

For those who use IDEA on Mac, the following works:

```
⌥ (Alt) + return
```

That is, press and hold Alt and hit return/enter.

Then select "Add type annotation to value definition".

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature request for a quick fix to insert inferred type in declarations ([scala-ide#1433](https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1001433)), but there has not been any contributions on it yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is not direct solution to your problem, but if you unit test those functions then your tests will "enforce" return types and will break when someone changes return types.

For example, in specs2 it could look something like:

```
foo(arg1) must be equalTo Success
```

Answer (score 1):

Another partial solution is the scalastyle SBT plugin (http://www.scalastyle.org/rules-0.2.0.html) which can warn you about public members with inferred types.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse: Hover over the identifier, click to expand the hover, triple-click to select all, Ctrl+C (or Cmd+C) to copy, click on the code to remove the hover, click back to where you were, Ctrl+V to paste, then finally delete all the wrong/over-verbose/redundant stuff.

It'd probably be quicker to just type in the correct type.

Does anyone have a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Using IDEA Intellij 15: File menu > Settings > Editor > Intentions

Minimize the Intentions and select Scala > Type and make sure that "Toggle Type Annotation" is checked.

Then when you select a (variable or function) definition and hit Alt+[Enter] it asks you if you want to insert the inferred type - hit [carriage-return] to do so.

I know that's 2 key-strokes, but it's still better than selecting, copying and pasting.